# Cannot open/create ASP.NET applications in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-10

I'm having trouble opening my projects in Visual Studio. I get the following error and the project does not load.

Creation of virtual directory failed with the following error: Filename:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config

Line number: 24

Error: The configuration section 'fulltrustassemblies' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration.

I tried creating a new ASP.NET webform application with target framework 4.7.2 (same as the ones of the project that does not load) and get the same issue.

Comment: clear solution and rebuild application may be will workout.

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try if adding the section to the file solve the problem?

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <system.web> 
            <fullTrustAssemblies> 
                <clear/>
            </fullTrustAssemblies> 
        </system.web> 
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That did not help. I get another error in line: 398 now

Comment: The configuration section system.xaml.hosting cannot be read because it is missing section declaration.

Comment: Add also <configuration>...</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

In the respective web.config file, you need to removed following element：

```
<fullTrustAssemblies>
                ....
</fullTrustAssemblies>
<partialTrustVisibleAssemblies />
```